# git pull -u without ref name works only with remotes other than origin

Tags: git

When checking out a new branch (`git checkout -b $BRANCH`), I often want to push it to a specific remote using the same branch name. I have two remotes, one named “origin” and one named “mine”. When I want to push such a new branch to “mine”, i can simply do

```
$ git push -u mine
```

This will push the branch to `refs/heads/$BRANCH` on the remote “mine” and start tracking it.

However, the same thing does not work for the “origin” remote:

```
$ git push -u origin
```

> ```
> fatal: The current branch $BRANCH has no upstream branch.
> To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use
>
>     git push --set-upstream origin $BRANCH
> ```

(Using `git push -u origin $BRANCH`, as the output suggests, of course works fine but I’d rather not repeat the branch name as I might mistype it.)

Why is one remote treated differently from the other?

Relevant snippet from my config file:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://git@server:/path/to/public/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    fetch = +refs/pull-requests/*/from:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
[remote "mine"]
    url = ssh://git@server:/path/to/my/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/mine/*
    fetch = +refs/pull-requests/*/from:refs/remotes/mine/pr/*
```

As you can see, these configs look the same (mutatis mutandis) yet produce such different behaviour. Is the name ”origin” somehow special or is there another config I need to look at?

I’m using git version 2.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Tracking branches have a remote and a remote branch associated - look at the branch in .git/config (`branch.*.remote` and `branch.*.merge`).
In case of your branch the remote is "mine".

Have a look at `push.default` in [`git-config(1)`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) - default behaviour (`simple`) is to push the current branch to the remote branch and branch's remote only when both branches have the same name.

Comment: Thanks, but that’s not it. `push.default` is `simple` but there is no config `branch.branchname.remote` or `branch.branchname.merge` for the current branch. And yet I reproducibly get this totally distinct behaviour for the two remotes.